# DDD, PHP and the Repository

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I am studying up on PHP and DDD.  It seems to me that the repository pattern is not particularly relevant to PHP, since PHP has a shared-nothing architecture.  Am I right?

I'm not saying that it doesn't apply, just that it is not as central as it is in languages that share objects between requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful:
http://phpmaster.com/handling-collections-of-aggregate-roots/